# Try to create NSString from bytes. It always returns an empty string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create a string from bytes a received via network. The NSString I het is always an empty one.

```
if (stringLength > 0) {
        NSData *bytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:data+1 length:stringLength];
        result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data+1 length:stringLength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
```

As I said I get an empty NSString. The string is a base64 encoded value so it should be valid utf-8 since it only contains ascii symbols.

Comment: That code looks good to me (apart from the memory leak if you're not using ARC).  The issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: What happens when you `NSLog("%@", data);` before you create the `NSData` object?  Is it empty then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your raw bytes aren't UTF-8 after all. Or maybe, because you're passing `data+1` instead of `data` itself, you're causing the encoding attempt to fail because the process thinks there's an improper UTF-8 encoding sequence. (Forgive me if I'm being presumptuous, but you have to take everything into account.) In any case, you're relying heavily on your assumption, and that's a trap we all fall into now and then.

Here's a strategy for you. If your attempt at creating an NSString instance using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` returns nil, then try using `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`. And if that returns nil, then try using `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`.

Even if, after all of that, you get a string that's not quite right, it's still better than a nil string in that it could help to show you if there's some other area in which you've made a mistake.

Good luck to you in your endeavors.

Comment: I rechecked the bytes and I noticed my mistake: I didn't account for the bytes that indicate the length of the string. I was starting the string with an integer. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's really base64 encoded..

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
CFDataRef decodedData;
SecTransformRef decoder;

decoder = SecDecodeTransformCreate(kSecBase64Encoding, &error);
if (error) {
    CFShow(error);
    exit(-1);
}

SecTransformSetAttribute(decoder,
                         kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
                         (CFDataRef *)bytes,
                         &error);

if (error) {
    CFShow(error);
    exit(-1);
}

decodedData = SecTransformExecute(decoder, &error);

if (error) {
    CFShow(error);
    exit(-1);
}
```